# Add nodes & edges in graph via networkx and using python

Tags: python, graph, networkx, scapy

I need to create a graph of IP addresses and mark edges between them for which I wrote the code below. The list, content of the parseOutput(), looks something like this :

```
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.206')
('216.58.208.206', '172.16.254.128')
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.226')
('216.58.208.226', '172.16.254.128')
('172.16.254.128', '8.8.8.8')
('8.8.8.8', '172.16.254.128')
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.227')
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.227')
('216.58.208.227', '172.16.254.128')
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.227')
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.227')
...
```

when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 40, in <module>
    g.add_nodes_from(nodeList)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py", line 429, in add_nodes_from
    nn,ndict = n
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

---

```
import logging, sys, struct, binascii, socket
from scapy.all import *
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pkts=rdpcap("pcapFile.pcap",20)

def parsePcap():
        IPList = [[] for i in range (20)]
        count = 0
        for pkt in pkts:
                #print pkt.summary()
                if pkt.haslayer(IP):
                        #proto = pkt.getLayer(IP).proto
                        x = pkt.getlayer(IP).src
                        y = pkt.getlayer(IP).dst
                        IPList[count]= (x,y)
                        #IPList[count].append(proto)
                        print IPList[count]
                        count += 1
        return IPList


parseOutput = parsePcap()
nodeList = parseOutput
edgeList = parseOutput

g = nx.Graph()

g.add_nodes_from(nodeList)
print g.number_of_nodes
g.add_edges_from(edgeList)

pos = nx.spring_layout(g,scale=1) #default to scale=1
nx.draw(g,pos)
```

I dont' even know what I'm doing wrong. The documentation doesn't tell much and
all examples online seem to be written in the same syntaxt as my code.

Comment: Please show the full traceback error message.

Comment: Could you provide an example content of the `parseOutput` variable as well? `nodeList = parseOutput` followed by `edgeList = parseOutput` looks strange here.

Comment: The list of IPs that I show just above the code is the exact values of parseOutput

Comment: @HappyLeapSecond updated with full traceback error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is caused by

```
IPList = [[] for i in range (20)]
```

which leads to `parsePcap()` returning a list of sequences with an empty list or lists at the end when `len(pkts)` is less than 20:

```
parseOutput = [
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.206'),
...
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.227'),
[],  #<---------------- This is causing the problem 
]
```

When `parseOutput` is passed to `g.add_nodes_from`,
you get the traceback error message:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py", line 429, in add_nodes_from
  nn,ndict = n
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

In retrospect, if you think carefully about the error message
you can see it is telling you that `n` has 0 values to unpack. That makes
sense if `n`, the node, is an empty list:

```
In [136]: nn, ndict = []
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

The empty list is coming from `parseOutput`.

---

Instead of pre-allocating a list of a fixed size:

```
IPList = [[] for i in range (20)]
```

the preferred way to do this in Python is to use the `append` method:

```
def parsePcap():
    IPList = []
    for pkt in pkts:
        if pkt.haslayer(IP):
            x = pkt.getlayer(IP).src
            y = pkt.getlayer(IP).dst
            IPList.append((x, y))
    return IPList
```

This is easier and more readable, since you do not need to fuss with index
numbers and increment a counter variable. Moreover, it allows you to handle an
arbitrary number of items in `pkts` without first having to know the length of
`pkts`.

---

Another thing that needs to be fixed is that the `nodeList` typically is not the
same as the `edgeList`.

If you are going to declare a `nodeList`,
the `nodeList` should be an iterable of IP addresses, and the edgeList
should be an iterable of tuples, like `parseOutput`:

```
nodeList = set([item for pair in parseOutput for item in pair])
print(nodeList)
# set(['216.58.208.206', '216.58.208.227', '172.16.254.128',
#  '216.58.208.226', '8.8.8.8'])
```

However, since all your nodes are also mentioned in edgeList, you can **omit declaring the nodes** and just use

```
edgeList = parseOutput
g.add_edges_from(edgeList)
```

`g.add_edges_from` will add the nodes implicitly.

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

parseOutput = [
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.206'),
('216.58.208.206', '172.16.254.128'),
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.226'),
('216.58.208.226', '172.16.254.128'),
('172.16.254.128', '8.8.8.8'),
('8.8.8.8', '172.16.254.128'),
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.227'),
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.227'),
('216.58.208.227', '172.16.254.128'),
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.227'),
('172.16.254.128', '216.58.208.227'),]

g = nx.Graph()
edgeList = parseOutput
g.add_edges_from(edgeList)

pos = nx.spring_layout(g,scale=1) #default to scale=1
nx.draw(g,pos, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

---

Comment: The error is all between what parsePcap spits out and what parseOutput should take. If I simply create a list of IPs and feed them to parseOutput, it seems to be running smoothly. but if I use the module that i wrote - parsePcap(), something seems to be off with its output and I see this error:

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 36, in <module>
    g.add_edges_from(edgeList)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py", line 781, in add_edges_from
    "Edge tuple %s must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple."%(e,))
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: Edge tuple [] must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple'

Comment: Aha. I can reproduce your error messages if I include an empty list at the end of `parseOutput`. See the last edit for an alternative version of `parsePcap`. This will create an `IPList` without empty lists at the end.

Comment: +1 @HappyLeapSecond - I did use append at some point in the past, but modified it to the current way. changing the code back to using append as the way to add IP edges and nodes took care of the error i posted last. THANKS!